# Get all Items, which have an String in an array, which are contained in a text

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

my Schema is:

```
var categorySchema = new Schema({
   name: { type: String, required: true },
   tags: [
        {tag: {type: String, required: true}}
   ]
});
```

Now i have a text and i want to see, if the text cointains one of the tags with a whitespace after it.

First of all, i want mongoose to handle the query. I don't know how to do it.

This is my try in node. It returns all Categories :

```
getAllIncludedCategories (text) {
  return Category.find()
     .then((categories) => { 
    return _.uniq(categories.filter((cat) => {
        return (
          this.isIn(text, cat.tags)
        )
      })
    )
  })
  .catch(error => console.log(error))
},

isIn(text, tagsArray) {
   return tagsArray.some((tag)=> {
      return (text + ' '.includes(tag + ' '));
   });
},
```

Comment: eagle eye ;)
My original schema is more complex, so this is not the problem. I wanted you to focus on my problem.

Comment: now it's correct. thanks :)